# strtok keep original char

Tags: programming

I want to make a vocab program for an arduino. The vocabs are saved in a char array seperated with an '/'. Now I want to split a random picked char and split it at the '/' so I can save it into two variables. But if I do it with strtok the original string gets sacrificed. If now the same vocab comes again...

I hope you can help me, but if you think a other way to do it would be better I'm open for suggestions.
Here's my code

```
long random1, random2, random3, random4;
int lengtharray = 5;    
char* vocab1;
char* vocab2;
char* vocab3;
char* vocab4;    
char* german1;
char* english1;    
char vocabs[5][16] = {"Apfel/apple","er/he","Zoo/zoo","sie/she","Hallo/hello"};

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); //Debugging
}

void loop() {
randomSeed(analogRead(0));
random1 = random(0,lengtharray); 
randomSeed(analogRead(0));
random2 = random(0,lengtharray);
while(random2 == random1){
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));
    random2 = random(0,lengtharray);
}
randomSeed(analogRead(0));
random3 = random(0,lengtharray);
while(random3 == random1 || random3 == random2){ 
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));
    random3 = random(0,lengtharray);
}
randomSeed(analogRead(0));
random4 = random(0,lengtharray);
while(random4 == random1 || random4 == random2 || random4 == random3){ 
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));
    random4 = random(0,lengtharray);
}

vocab1 = vocabs[random1];
vocab2 = vocabs[random2];
vocab3 = vocabs[random3];
vocab4 = vocabs[random4];

Serial.println(vocab1);
Serial.println(vocab2);
Serial.println(vocab3);
Serial.println(vocab4);
Serial.println("//");
delay(1000);

german1 = strtok(vocab1,"/");
english1 = strtok(NULL,"/");
Serial.println(german1);
Serial.println(english1);
}
```

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: Personally I would store them as separate words within a `struct` to pair them up. No splitting required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would take a completely different tack. I'd store the word pairs as separate items within a struct:

```
struct wordpair {
    const char *german;
    const char *english;
};

struct wordpair pairs[] = {
    { "Apfel", "apple" },
    { "er", "he" },
    { "Zoo", "zoo" },
    { "sie", "she" },
    { "Hallo", "hello" },
};

#define NWORDS (sizeof(pairs) / sizeof(pairs[0]))
```

Now you have instant access to the words.  For example:

```
pairs[3].german
```

is `"sie"`, and

```
pairs[3].english
```

is `"she"`.

You don't need to waste time splitting words up, since they are already split up.  You don't need to worry about words getting corrupted, because you're never writing anything to the words.  Indeed, if you tried to, because they are tagged as `const`, the compiler should complain.

So:

```
struct wordpair *vocab1 = &pairs[random1];

Serial.println(vocab1->german);
```

The macro `NWORDS` gives you the size of the array for easy reference.

Answer (score 1):

Make a buffer large enough to hold the largest of the word-pairs. Copy the selected pair into the buffer and run strtok() in that buffer. Strtok will damage the buffer contents but that is a throw-away; the original word-pair string is still unchanged.